# How to align square boxes in a straight line in a mobile/tablet view in html/css?

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, media-queries

I have a **screenshot as shown below** which I have replicated in the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/n1mo8trb/7/embedded/result/). At this moment, it looks extremely good in desktop view. 
[image]

The snippets of CSS codes which I have used in order to align the square boxes in a desktop view are:

```
.squares .square {
    width: 13%;
    text-align: center;
    height: 150px;
    padding-top: 1%;
    padding-left: 1%;
    padding-right: 1%;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 3px;
    border-color: rgb(145, 147, 150);
    border-radius: 10px;


}
```

When I am seeing the fiddle in the mobile view, its looking extremely un-organize.

[image]

**Problem Statement:**

I am wondering what changes I should make in the fiddle so that in the mobile view **3 square boxes come in one row** and the other **2 square boxes come in the middle below it** (or **2 in one and 2 in another row will also work**).

I tried using media queries as shown below but for some reasons I am not able to replicate what I want.

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 767px) {
.squares .square {
    width: 41%;
    text-align: center;
    height: 150px;
    margin-bottom: 11%;
    padding-top: 1%;
    padding-left: 1%;
    padding-right: 1%;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 3px;
    border-color: rgb(145,147,150);
    border-radius: 10px;
}
}
```

Comment: Maybe consider using `display: flex; flex-flow: row wrap;` on the parent

Comment: @Adam Thanks for the answer. I am wondering if you can update it in the fiddle.

Answer (score 0):

That's what flexbox is for. I've done little model for you to recreate it for your purpose. It will probably need some media queries for smaller displays, but that's for your taste to do it well. Use this guide for more reference - [CSS-Tricks Flexbox Guide](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/).

```css
.container {
  background: #1D1F20;
  padding: 1em 2em;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  align-items: center;
  
}

.card {
  width: 120px;
  height: auto;
  background: #fff;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 1em;
  margin: 1em 0;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

.image img {
  width: 100%;
  object-fit: contain;
}

.text {
  padding: 0 1em;
}

.text p {
  -webkit-margin-after: 0; /* resetting predefined margin */
}

.arrows {
  padding: 0.5em;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="card">
    <div class="image">
      <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/150x150" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="text">
      <p>Nibh Risus Pellentesque</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="arrows">
    <div><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/100x100" alt=""></div>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <div class="image">
      <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/150x150" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="text">
      <p>Nibh Risus Pellentesque</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="arrows">
    <div><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/100x100" alt=""></div>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <div class="image">
      <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/150x150" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="text">
      <p>Nibh Risus Pellentesque</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="arrows">
    <div><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/100x100" alt=""></div>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <div class="image">
      <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/150x150" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="text">
      <p>Nibh Risus Pellentesque</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="arrows">
    <div><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/100x100" alt=""></div>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <div class="image">
      <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/150x150" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="text">
      <p>Nibh Risus Pellentesque</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="arrows">
    <div><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/100x100" alt=""></div>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <div class="image">
      <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/150x150" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="text">
      <p>Nibh Risus Pellentesque</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```